# UISwitch in UITableView Bug

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have an UISwitch in my UITableViewCell prototype.

The problem is, when I turn on one of the switches, one of the not shown switches also gets turned on.

This doesn't happen in the iPad version where all cells are shown.

Here is some code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    Notification *notification = [notifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:100];
    UISwitch *newsSwitch = (UISwitch *) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:102];

    [titleLabel setText:[notification name]];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[notification image]]];

    BOOL isOn = [storage boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"notification_%@", [notification name]]];
    [newsSwitch setOn:isOn];
    [newsSwitch setTag:indexPath.row];
    [newsSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangeStateForSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You mean, a switch that is not yet on screen also gets turned on? Then the bug is most likely in your `didChangeStateForSwitch:` method, please update your question and show us the code for this method.

Comment: I removed the code from didChangeStateForSwitch: and the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you first query the switch via its tag:

```
UISwitch *newsSwitch = (UISwitch *) [cell viewWithTag:101];
```

But later on, you change that tag:

```
[newsSwitch setTag:indexPath.row];
```

So when the cell gets reused, the switch won't be found as now its tag isn't 101 any more. Therefor, the switch will be stuck in its old state.

You can easily verify this by adding a `NSLog(@"Switch: %@", newsSwitch);` after querying the switch. You'll see that it'll output `Switch: (null)` for those rows where you have "wrong" switch values.

The solution this is to not modify the tag.

Question is, how do you remember which row the switch is for, then? One way would be this:

```
- (void)didChangeStateForSwitch:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:[sender superview]];
    ...
}
```

Another possibility is to use [associated objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/).

Comment: your answer is correct, that was the problem. the solution didn't work for me though. I created the UISwitch programmatically. it works fine now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First time when you load the cell you are taking the view with tag 101 for switch.Few lines after that you are setting new tag to this switch and next time when you try to take the view with tag 101 it doesn't exist.`[newsSwitch setTag:indexPath.row];`  delete this line and try again

You can get the index path as @DarkDust suggested

```
- (void)didChangeStateForSwitch:(id)sender
{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:[sender superview]];
...
}
```

Comment: the "[storage boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"notification_%@", [notification name]]];" is not enough?

Comment: That happened to me before. Just as @wootage said you should keep your switch states in an array and set it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You have to implement CustomTableViewCell and give the uniq tag to each Switch, to resolwe it in didChangeStateForSwitch!

Comment: Yes, customCell is good option but you don't need tag for the switch , you can get them from the cell indexPath and handle the switch event in the customCell class

Comment: He explicitly reads the desired state from a storage and changes the switch state, so that is not the problem.